# find closure set of a topology

Tags: general-topology

if $(\mathbb{N},\tau)$ is topological space with $\tau = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{E_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$,where   $E_{n}:=\{n,n+1, ...\}$. Given $A= \{3,4,5\}$ and $B = \{1,2,7,9\}$ find $cl(A)$ , $cl(B)$?

Comment: What are the closed sets in your space? This is similar to the co-finite topology. The closure is the smallest closed set containing the set you are trying for the find the closure for.

Comment: I think closed set is {$\phi$ , N ,{1},{1,2},{1,2,3},..} or am I wrong ?

Comment: In your definition, does a topology consist of closed sets or of open sets? I.e., are the $E_n$ closed or open?

Comment: As noted by @IrbidMath, you must use the definition of closure on a set $A$. It's defined as the intersection of all sets that are closed and that contain $A$.

Comment: If you are using a "different" definition of closure. Then try to prove that it's equivalent to my above definition. For example, the kuratowski closure axioms

Comment: @LukasJuhrich consist of open sets

Comment: @3jiwiojr3 I have to get famliy of closed sets F which is complement of every element of $\tau$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit confused about your notation. But, $cl(A) = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $cl(B) = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. I am using the definition of closure and closed.

Comment: i was thinking that but my professor said cl(A) = N , cl(B) = N and that was weird so I had to ask here to make sure that I'm right

Comment: Based upon the information you have given me, I am pretty sure that is not True. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Closure_(Topology). Look at definition 2 since it's a very common definition of closure. We know that $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is closed that contains $A$. So, already it's impossible that $cl(A) = \mathbb{N}$